# my iOS app update deletes persistent data from users' older version

Tags: ios, user-interface, ios7, persistent-storage

In my iOS application, I allow user's to save their UI presets.

```
NSArray* theDirs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory
                                                          inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
NSURL *supportDir = [theDirs objectAtIndex:0];
NSURL *presetURL = [supportDir URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Presets"];

// Write to disk.
NSData *presetData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:mainDict format:NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0 options:0 error:nil];
NSString *presetPath = [[presetURL path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.preset", presetName]];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:presetPath]) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:presetPath error:nil];
}
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:presetPath contents:presetData attributes:nil];
```

I have just released an update on the app store for iOS7. User's have emailed me complaining that their presets have been erased upon updating....

Is it the directory I've chosen to use (support) ???

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: I am not sure why you chose the support directory, but using one of [common iOS directories](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) has not given me any problems. I think it would be best on iOS to choose one of these that suits your needs.

Comment: I didn't write the app originally. I'm just upgrading it for audiobus and ios7.  but this is good to know in general. thanks for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the document's directory. You can access it like this:

```
NSArray *directoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *directory = [directoryPath objectAtIndex:0];
```

You should be free to add/remove files/directories to your hearts content here.

Comment: Yes.  I will begin saving presets to the documents directory, and if the application support directory exists, copy any existing presets to the documents directory and wipe them. Then push a maintenance update.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the issue is with this code:

```
NSArray* theDirs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
```

According to the [Foundation Constants Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSSearchPathDirectory) `NSApplicationSupportDirectory` is:

> **NSApplicationSupportDirectory**
>
> Location of application support files
>   (`Library/Application Support`).
>   Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
>   Declared in NSPathUtilities.h.

AFAIK there is no such folder exist in the iPhone device, probably that'll be the reason.